# Activate the second combobox when first is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two combobox on my usercontrol. My target is, when the first is selected(with an item inside) then the second should be active.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RestoreComputer.Views.ConfigView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="50">
            <ComboBox Name="_server" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Servers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Server}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="100"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="18"/>
            <Image Source="../Images/narrow.png" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
            <ComboBox Name="_computer" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I activate the second combobox, when the first is item selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using databinding, you can create a boolean property in your viewmodel and set it to true when Server property is set. And bind that property to your second combobox enabled property.

In your viewmodel

```
private bool comboEnabled = false;
public bool ComboEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return comboEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        comboEnabled = value;
        onPropertyChanged("ComboEnabled");
    }
}

//and in your Server property
public Server
{
    get---YourCode{}
    set
    {
        if(value != null)
        ComboEnabled = true;
        ---Yourcode
    }
}

//and in your xaml
<ComboBox Name="_computer" IsEnabled="{Binding ComboEnabled }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Active - u mean "Enable"?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        comboBox2.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Or even simpler

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        comboBox2.Enabled = comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SelectionChanged event on the first combobox:
(this can be done in wpf or on your Load event)

```
_server.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
```

Get the method

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object o, eventArgs e)
{
 //Do whatever you want to do with the selection data
 DoSomething();

 //Focus the second combobox:
 _computer.Focus();
}
```